Deactivate externally integrated Javascript file with Javascript
I have included the following in my header code (Google AdSense).
Now I am looking for a way to deactivate this line via Javascript:
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://domain.tld/javascript-file.js"></script>

Using CSS (Display:None) does not work because this code will be executed anyway.
I want to deactivate this line using an external JS (so that it is no longer executed) if this is defined in this external JS.
Thanks.

Can you edit this html file? i mean can you write a script to run before this script tag?

Yes, i can do that.

If it's just for your own usage, just ublock. But, wait.. if you can edit the file, just remove that line..

Exactly, if you can edit the file just remove it. you don't need to write some extra code.

I want to change this dynamically without removing that line, so if my external js file change (trough some php script) that I remove / block that execution, if my external js file change again it would be activated again

Write this before script tag to remove the specific script tag before it executes:
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var scriptTags = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  for(let idx = scriptTags.length-1; idx >= 0; idx--){
    if(scriptTags[idx].src == "https://domain.tld/javascript-file.js"){
       var parent = scriptTags[idx].parentNode; 
       if(parent) parent.removeChild(scriptTags[idx]); 
    } 
  }
});

try this. Only if the script tag is a part of your document structure and hasn't been run yet will this function. Obviously, once the script has run, it cannot be removed.
After discussion in comments answer edit.
const loadExternalScript = (someCondition) => {
  return someYourCondition;
};

// Check if the external script
if (loadExternalScript(true)) {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "https://domain.tld/javascript-external-new-file.js";
  document.head.appendChild(script);
} else {
  console.log("External Script did not load.");
}

This is i tried a condition for conditionally loading the selected external script. You can edit/modify it.

Thanks will test that tomorrow, maybe there is another option if some url exists it includes the script if not it includes nothingy maybe it's simplier? Going on from this example: https://gist.github.com/JulianGarciaDev/256bdec5247ad92f9317a79532b11ba7

Or an external js file that creates the DOM on a if condition?

@Omexlu i did not understand your 2nd comment properly. But if the URL is already loaded and carried out after your DOM manipulation logic, you won`t be able to prevent it from improving the DOM. Furthermore, you can prevent using in if logic. i have written, you can modify it. Sorry for misunderstanding

Thanks for your example, I meant maybe create an external JS script where my logic takes place in it and then with an IF where then a script element is created and if condition is not met the script element is not created, that might be easier and nicer than the above version ? :)

@Omexlu I tried and updated the answer with basic condition check. You can modify it according to your need or if it helped you, you can upvote and accept it :-)

Thanks you for this, I will try this tomorrow but it seems to be good, the else statement I can remove so if the condition is not meet nothing happens?
